# How can you sort infortmation from csv file you opened

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a code that opens file containing tracks, artist, albums, which reads in the following style 'Computer Love, Kraftwerk, Computer World\n', 'Paranoid Android. I need to organize them and make a list with the tracks information in the following way

```
 TRACK ARTIST ALBUM
Paranoid Android Radiohead OK Computer
```

(for example)

Here is the code I came up with so far:

```
def display_playlist( filename ):
    lines = []
    for line in f:
       lines.append(line)
    return lines 

with open('geek-music.csv', 'r') as f:
    contents = display_playlist(f)
print(contents)
```

How can I organize them

Comment: check this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could approach this is to use a Pandas dataframe. Some sample code would be:

Read the data into pandas, assuming it has no header.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('geek-music.csv', header=None, names=['track','artist','album'])
```

Now you have a dataframe representation you can manipulate to sort as needed (by using sort_values, e.g. to sort by track:

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values('track', ascending=True)
```

I'm not exactly sure what your end goal is here - to print this on screen or to write to a file? If you wanted to write to a file using space separated variables, you can do:

```
sorted_df.to_csv('output', sep=" ")
```

If you wanted to print it on screen with the space separator, perhaps you could use iterrows.

```
for row in sorted_df.iterrows():
    print "{} {} {}".format(row['track'], row['artist'], row['album'])
```

Note, code untested so may contain some syntax errors!